# Automatically retry deleting of file to be replaced with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have to wait 5-10 seconds and then click *Retry* on our DBNetServices for our PlazSales point of sale software. Is there a way for it to automatically wait at least for a while?

Error:

> An error occurred while trying to replace the existing file:
>   DeleteFile failed; code 5; Access is denied. Click retry to try
>   again...

```
[Setup]
CloseApplications=yes   

[Files]
Source: {#AutoBackupNetwork}\DBNetService.exe; DestDir: {app}\server; \
    Flags: IgnoreVersion overwritereadonly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a custom logic for deleting the file like:

```
[Files]
Source: {#AutoBackupNetwork}\DBNetService.exe; DestDir: {app}\server; \
    Flags: IgnoreVersion overwritereadonly; BeforeInstall: DeleteWithRetry
```

```pascal
[Code]

procedure DeleteWithRetry;
var
  Path: string;
  Timeout: Integer;
  Step: Integer;
begin
  Path := ExpandConstant('{app}\server\DBNetService.exe');
  if FileExists(Path) then
  begin
    Log(Format('%s exists, will try to delete', [Path]));
    Timeout := 5000;
    Step := 100;
    while (Timeout > 0) and (not DeleteFile(Path)) do
    begin
      Log(Format('Failed to delete %s, will try again in %d ms', [Path, Step]));
      Sleep(Step);
      Timeout := Timeout - Step;
    end;
  end;
end;
```